# How to redirect an IFrame Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

so I recently set up a shop with GoDaddy and IFramed it on my site, however when I try and checkout the iframe is denied, I'm trying to get it to where I can click that button in the iframe and it will redirect me to the link it's supposed to go to.

The store is at https://cryodev.net/testing/home/shop.html

This occurs when you add an item and then try to checkout.

I tried checking for the code, but I haven't done that before so I don't know.

I tried this code:

```
   <head>
<title>Shop</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://cryohosting.godaddysites.com/" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
           <script type=text/javascript >
    $('#frame').contents().find( "body" ).html('<button data-aid="CART_CHECKOUT" class="x-el x-el-button x-ntrl-def x-btn x-b-0 x-b-rad-md x-c-act-bg x-c-act-bg-hover x-d-inline-block x-va-middle x-m-b-0-bpxs x-p-t-xs-bpxs x-p-b-xs-bpxs x-p-r-md-bpxs x-p-l-md-bpxs x-f-alt-fam x-f-sz-md x-c-act-text x-c-act-text-hover x-ta-center-bpxs x-ws-normal x-cur-pointer  x-d-aid">Checkout</button>')
    <meta http-equiv=“refresh" content="0"; url=https://example.com/" />

        $('#frame').load(function() {
  $('#frame').replaceWith('<p>hi</p>');
});
    Your browser doesn't support iframes, go to https://cryohosting.godaddysites.com/ for store.
    </script>
</iframe>

</body>
```

But it didn't work... :/

I want the button "Checkout" to redirect to https://5053d4df-8dcd-4a91-b205-405c1ee42ddd.mysimplestore.com/checkout/address

Comment: When the contents of the iFrame is not from the same origin as the main page, you can neither add script to the iFrame from the main page  nor have the iFrame manipulate the parent. Additionally the script you are showing has a weird `<meta http-equiv=“refresh" content="0"; url=https://example.com/" />` in the middle of it. Also you need to use //ajax.google.... to keep the protocols the same

Comment: So start by fixing `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://...l' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Thanks, I did all of this late last night and I completely failed to notice it was loading through http, so what do you do next?

Comment: Change `src="http://ajax ...` to `src="https//ajax...` or src="//ajax - the last us only useful if you also have http version of your site